# Как создать строчку, состоящую из n пробелов

Tags: c++, строки, вывод

На начинающем уровне, для университета, не судите строго. Нужно сдать некую таблицу, заполненную данными. Первый столбец хочу выровнять, но так получилось что длина переменных записанных в первом столбце колеблется. Это значение не больше 20, поэтому я хочу создать переменную, в которую хочу записать количество пробелов `space -= strlen(string1)`. Реально ли сложить строки? Так как цикл `for(i = 0; i < space; i++){cout << " ";}` не получилось запихнуть в `cout`(оооочень наивный)

Comment: что значит не получилось?.. работать будет даже так.

Comment: char space[21] = {0};
memset(space, ' ', 20);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В C++ это делается так:

```
string s(20,' ');
```

Но, по-моему, вы не с того конца беретесь за задачу. Посмотрите на форматирование вывода. Например, [вот](https://ideone.com/uzZTjK) вывод разной длины чисел в виде строгих столбцов:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
{
    cout << setw(12) << rand();
    if (i%3 == 2) cout << "\n";
}
```

Словом, вам [сюда](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).